# How to perform Partial Credit Rasch modelling on multi-sessional assessments

Tags: rasch

I am evaluating the effect of a number of examiners (who examine in pairs) on the marking scores of candidates.

As a background, there are multiple, separate sessions (I am looking into over a 100), with each session having between 30 - 40 candidates. Each candidate has 4 x 5 questions, and is seen by 4 pairs of examiners. Questions are of course different between sessions.

I am interested in using Rasch modelling, but experience is limited.

I have checked such analysis per session (20+ examiners per session, with 30+ candidates). Although results are fine, the fit of each model (SRMSR) is way above 0.05. Similarly unfit / outfit tests.

I am not sure if this is because of the small sample, or how to interpret this? Should I pool all sessions together?

Thanks